# Canonical Landscape Package Search daemon

Tags: networking, server, maas, openstack, landscape

I've a problem with my Landscape Server. Month ago I installed Canonical Landscape quickstart 18.04 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The reason that I don't use the last version is, adding the repository doesn't work on the latest Ubuntu version (20.04 LTS).

During the installation Landscape quickstart didn't create an self-signed certificate, so I decided to create it like described on Landscape's official website https://help.landscape.canonical.com/LDS/SSL
Everything was good for the first clients. I could copy the public certificate on the client and let them join.

After 3-4 weeks there was an Linux client who should connect with the Landscape Server but didn't work. I did just the same thing like I did for the other client, but still doesn't connect. I looked to the services of the landscape-server and everything was up and running except landscape-package-search the error was just 'Failed to start Landscape's Package Search daemon'.

I've also checked the certificates but everything was good. But when I try to connect the client with the server it returns me 'We were unable to contact the server. Your internet connection may be down. The landscape client will continue to try and contact the server periodically.' I checked also to ping to the server with his FQDN name and his ip address and that worked too.

After that I've looked also in to the broker.log file of the client and I saw this error: ' Error 35: gnutls_handshake() failed: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.' I checked the version of my curl package but it was already the newest version. So I don't know what to do next.

Update: I could solve it, I've just generate new certificates and reconfigured landscape-server-quickstart. But now I have an other problem everything is up and running, no error, but I can't go to the website of the server.

Is there something that I can't see. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Both Landscape 18.03 (I assume this is the version you mean) and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS were out of support by the time this question was asked.

You should install Landscape 19.10 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS for the most up to date version of Landscape on the most recently supported Ubuntu LTS.

See [here](https://docs.ubuntu.com/landscape/en/landscape-install-quickstart).